# tkinterのテキストボックスのサイズを自由に設定したい

Tags: python3

tkinterでGUIアプリを作成しているのですが、テキストボックスのサイズを自由に設定したいと考えています。
現在のコードは以下のようになっております。

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tkinter.Tk()

# コンボボックスの作成(rootに配置,リストの値を編集不可(readonly)に設定)
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, state='readonly')
# リストの値を設定
combo["values"] = ("IDを選択","@realDonaldTrump","@justinbieber","@ladygaga","@BarackObama","@katyperry")
# デフォルトの値を食費(index=0)に設定
combo.current(0)
# コンボボックスの配置
combo.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'nsew')

#エントリー
EditBox = tkinter.Entry(width=50)
EditBox.insert(tkinter.END,"挿入する文字列")
EditBox.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'nsew')

get_b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text = '取得')
get_b1.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = 'nsew')

tw_txt = tkinter.Entry(width=20)
tw_txt.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = 'nsew')

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

しかし、イメージ図は以下のようです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのようにしたら再現できるでしょうか。
よろしくおねがい致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/199908

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実現したことはこんな感じでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コードの修正箇所は

- 右側のテキストボックスの配置を右側のグリッド**縦３つ**を使用するようにパラメータを `column=1, row=0, rowspan=3` に修正
- 右側のWidgetは複数行の入力が可能なようにEntry Wdigetから Text Widgetに変更
- 右側の３つのWidgetは特にFill(グリッド全体に拡大)して表示する必要が無いので、 `sticky='nsew'` のパラメータを削除
- Windowを拡大した際に右側のgridのエリアは拡大する必要がないので、`root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)` をコメントアウト`
- Windowを拡大した際に縦方向にも全体を拡大できうように、`grid_rowconfigure()` を追加
- あと右側中央のテキストボックスが少し窮屈だったのでマージン `padx=10, pady=10` を追加

で、以下が修正をいれたコードとなります

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tkinter.Tk()

# コンボボックスの作成(rootに配置,リストの値を編集不可(readonly)に設定)
combo = ttk.Combobox(root, state='readonly')
# リストの値を設定
combo["values"] = ("IDを選択","@realDonaldTrump","@justinbieber","@ladygaga","@BarackObama","@katyperry")
# デフォルトの値を食費(index=0)に設定
combo.current(0)
# コンボボックスの配置
combo.grid(column = 0, row = 0) #sticky = 'nsew'削除

#エントリー
EditBox = tkinter.Entry(width=50)
EditBox.insert(tkinter.END,"挿入する文字列")
EditBox.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx=10, pady=10) #sticky = 'nsew'削除

get_b1 = tkinter.Button(root, text = '取得')
get_b1.grid(column = 0, row = 2) #sticky = 'nsew'削除

tw_txt = tkinter.Text(width=20)
tw_txt.grid(column=1, row=0, rowspan=3, sticky = 'nsew') #配置を変更

# root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1) 右側エリアは拡大の必要ないのでいらない
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1) # 追加
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight = 1) # 追加
root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight = 1) # 追加

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: まさにその通りです。ありがとうございます。